# eval evaluates to a tuple

Tags: python, matrix

I have three indexes, `x,y,t` and a tridimensional matrix (it's actually a netcdf variable) in python but the order in which the indexes have to be applied to the matrix change. So, to make it easily user-definable I am trying to get the specific element I want as

```
order='t,x,y'  # or 't,y,x' or anything like this
elem=matrix[eval(order)]
```

but this fails with `TypeError: illegal subscript type`. When I try

```
a=eval(order)
print type(a)
```

it gives me that `a` is a tuple, so I'm guessing this is the source of my problem. But why is `a` a tuple? Any ideas as how to do this? Documentation wasn't helpful.

Also, somehow doing

```
a=eval(order)
i,j,k=a
elem=matrix[i,j,k]
```

doesn't work either. Not sure as to why.

**EDIT**

People are misunderstanding what I'm trying to do here apparently, so let me explain a little better. This is inside a function where the values `x`, `y`, `t` are already defined. However, the order in which to apply those indexes should be provided by the user. So the call would be something like `func(order='t,x,y')`. That's at least the only way I figured the user could pass the *order* of the indexes as a parameter. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `a` is a tuple because you are using commas; it is the comma that defines a tuple, not the parentheses.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I editted the question. Hopefully it will make more sense now. It was, indeed, lacking some crucial information. Let me know if it needs further editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to avoid using `eval` for this.  It's hacky and ugly, and it's easily possible to avoid it just by making a lookup dict.

```
>>> order = 'x,y,t'  # this is specified outside your function
```

You can still pass this string into your function if you want:

```
>>> # this is inside your function:
>>> t,x,y = 0,1,2  # I don't know what your actual values are..
>>> lookup = {'t': t, 'x': x, 'y': y}  # make this inside your function
>>> tuple_ = tuple(lookup[k] for k in order.split(','))  
>>> tuple_
(1, 2, 0)
```

Now use the `tuple_` to index your array.

Answer (score 1):

**Why is `a` a tuple?**

Because it is: if you leave `eval()` out of the picture, you get the same, when you are *just using commas*:

```
>>> a = 1, 2, 3
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
```

**do instead this:**

Give the order directly as list, lists maintain order:

```
def some_method(order=None):
    order = order or [t, y, x]  
    # t, y, x have to be known out side this scope         
    ...
```

If your `t, x, y` are only known within the scope, you - of course - have to
give the order in a symbolic way, thus back to eval. Here you assume knowledge about the inner state of your function

```
def some_method(order='t,x,y'):
    order = eval(order)
    ...
    elem = matrix[order[0]][order[1]][order[2]]
```

*EDIT*

[wims answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30350844/450517) shows how to avoid `eval()` which should be preferred *at least* when the input to this function would come from an untrusted source, because `eval()` would gladly run arbitrary python code.

Comment: But when I call `func(order=[t,y,x])` from the main function won't it give me an error because neither `t`,`x` or `y` are defined in the main function? They are only defined within `func`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is called "slicing", or even "extended slicing", depending on the data format you're slicing. Oh, and you don't need `eval` for that at all, tuples would do just fine.

See also this question:
[Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: It's not really slicing, it's plain old `__getitem__`

Comment: But +1 anyway for mentioning the eval is useless here

Comment: @wim can you then show me a way of doing this without `eval`? I know it's ugly but I can't think of another way.